# Calling Java from Python

Tags: java, python

I have a Java app that takes a long time to be initialized (so I can't use a command-line like interface) and I need to pass text and receive the output of a Java method from Python. Is it possible to load the Java application, have it open all the time the Python script runs and use a method from that app?

Comment: If you are running Jython it is easy

Comment: +1 for Jython. It's seamless to use Java from within the Jython interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the use of Python helps all that much over a command line (at least not a *nix command line), but the basic idea is to communicate over a socket or some similar mechanism. That means that the Java application will have to be wrapped in some code which opens a socket and waits for the python script to contact it. If you are most comfortable with python, you could look to implement that wrapper in [Jython](http://www.jython.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I've used JPype for something similar and it worked great.

[JPype](http://jpype.sourceforge.net/) is an effort to allow python programs full access to java class libraries. This is achieved not through re-implementing Python, as Jython/JPython has done, but rather through interfacing at the native level in both Virtual Machines.

If the java app is running you should also consider [xml-rpc](http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html) as it also works well.

Answer (score 0):

Py4J is a way to call Java from a python script. Here is the project website: http://py4j.sourceforge.net/